# Windows 8: Files show up in search in the file explorer, but not normally

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-search, file-search

I was cleaning up my hard drive recently, and I encountered several archive files that I could find when using search in file explorer, but not normally. When I checked the files properties, all have a file size of 0 bytes. Is there any way to remove these files?

Comment: Why can't you delete from the search results?

Comment: Gah, right I forgot to include that bit, it's impossible to delete them from the search results. When I attempt to it tells me the files have been moved but that is the only location they show up in.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming even after you deleted the files, windows still maintains a cache of them, hence shown in the search results as most files are indexed by windows.

What you can do here is try clearing the cache:

Here is how you do it:

right click on the hard-drive -> properties -> Disk Cleanup -> check recycle bin, temporary files and thumbnails and click on ok.

I believe this will solve your problem.

Hope it helped. :)